# bulk update ubercart stock and threshold values

Tags: ubercart, views

I have [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) running on my Drupal site and would like to bulk update my product stock levels.

I would like to accomplish this using a [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) Execute PHP Code operation. What code will update stock levels? I have thought about updating the stock table, `uc_product_stock`, but products without stock levels are not entered into the table.

Also, how do I set an initial stock value for all products?